# Zabbix3.0のテーブル作成及び初期データ登録の際のcreate.sql.gzの所在

Tags: zabbix

dockerにCentOS7のコンテナーを準備してzabbix Serverのインストールを試みています。

http://qiita.com/atanaka7/items/294a639effdb804cfdaa

のサイトをたよりに
・Zabbix LLCリポジトリを登録

```
# yum install http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.0/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.0-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

・Zabbix関連のパッケージをインストール

```
yum install zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql zabbix-web-japanese zabbix-agent
```

しかし、テーブルを作成して初期データを登録しようとしたところ、

```
# zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.0/create.sql.gz | mysql -uroot zabbix
```

のcreate.sql.gzファイルが見つかりません。

他にも検索しましたcreate.sql.gzだけを持ってくるような情報はありませんでした。
こちら何かにファイル名が変更されている可能性はありますでしょうか？
もしくは正常なやり方をご存知であればご教示お願いします。

Comment: リポジトリにある最新版がインストールされると思いますので、もしかしたら、`/usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.8/create.sql.gz` になるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: find / -name create.sql.gz -print で探して見ても見つからず、/usr/share/doc/配下のzabbix-se‌​rver-mysql-x.x.xのようなディレクトリ自体も無いようです。何かを入れ忘れているのでしょうか。

Comment: `rpm -ql zabbix-server-mysql | grep 'create\.sql'` とすると結果はどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.8/create.sql.gzと出ます。

Comment: もう一度、yum install zabbix-server-mysqlを試しましたが、Package zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.8-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest versionと状態です。なぜかインストールされません？？

Comment: 例えば `ls -l /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.8/create.sql.gz` とするとファイルが無い状態なのでしょうか？

Comment: ls: cannot access /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql-3.0.8/create.sql.gz: No such file or directory　という状態でありません。不思議です。

Comment: う〜ん、確かに不思議ですね…一旦アンインストールして、再度インストールしてみるとかですかね…

Comment: yum remove zabbix-server-mysql zabbix-web-mysql zabbix-web-japanese zabbix-agentを行い、再度インストールを実施しましたがdoc以下のzabbix-server-mysql-x.x.xが存在しません。docのパーミッションを777にして再度uninstall&installしても同じ状態で存在しません。こちらレポジトリが悪いということはありますか？

Comment: レポジトリをrpm -ivh http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.2/rhel/7/x86_64/zabbix-release-3.2-1.el7.noarch.rpmに変えて実施しましたが、存在しません。こちらdockerが悪さしているということはないでしょうか？

Comment: `rpm -ql zabbix-server-mysql` の結果から、パッケージが正常にインストールされたはずだと思われるのですが…おっしゃる通り、docker に起因する問題かもしれませんね。

Comment: dockerをインストール側でyum install zabbix-server-mysqlを行なったところ、create.sql.gzが取り出せましたので、それをコンテナーに移動させて実施した所成功しました。

Comment: /etc/yum.conf に tsflags=nodocs が設定されていると、/usr/share/doc/ 以下のファイルがインストールされません。容量を少なくするためかと。

Comment: tsflags=nodocsが設定されていました。原因はこれですね。

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya それが原因だったのですね。できれば、どちらかの方が回答していただけないでしょうか(Upvote したいので)。